# POST commands being called in access log

Tags: php, wordpress

I have already been to this site:
http://www.google.com/webmasters/hacked/
so I am in the process of quarantining our site and changing passwords. But my question has to do with the post commands in our access log. The most common ones are:

> "POST /event/actionscript-june-201/trackback/ HTTP/1.1" 200 983
>   "http://www.brookwood.com/event/actionscript-june-201/"

and

> "POST /wp-content/indexfoMt.php HTTP/1.1" 200 983 "-" "-"
>   brookwood.com

The biggest problem with both of these is that neither one of them are actually creating a file, it is like the indexfoMt file is created and deleted off the server, because there is no such file there.

So my question is, how can I best go through my wordpress site to make sure I have purged all of the content of hacked code? I know it is possible changing passwords could fix the problem, how likely is it that it will rid the access log of these calls?

Finally, how long should I keep my site quarantined, Google does not give us any indication of how long to keep a site quarantined.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Someone is probably using your WordPress installation to attack something. I faced it for a few days now on my own CentOS box which hosts several WordPress blogs. You will probably not be able to solve this by just going through your WordPress site. You have to log in into the box or ask your provider to do it for you.

Download `nethogs` and see which process is transferring more data than expected. If it is for example the process named `host` then see which files it is using with `lsof` (see below). Then you will probably find out which WordPress installation is affected. Then go to the WordPress folder and look for new, suspicious files.

In my case that looked like this. See `bruteforce.so`.

```
[root@/domain/ logs]# lsof | grep 1706
...
host       1706 /domain/  cwd       DIR              253,0     4096      10178 /home//domain//public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven
...
host       1706 /domain/  DEL       REG              253,0                 656 /home//domain//public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/bruteforce.so
```

And if you were compromised than recreate your server and use backup to restore it like stated in https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server.

Comment: we cannot restore from backup now, too much time passed since 12/27.
I am not sure how nethogs will help - it looks on the surface to be a tool that analyzes my processes on my machine, I need to check our domain - but that may be what you meant by ask your provider to do it (they have been of little help to me, but I will try again.)
I don't think this is a bruteforce attack, because I am not seeing any post requests into wp-login. But like I said before, I am seeing a lot of post calls into indexfoMt.php, which does not exist, but looks like it is trying to get into main part of site.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find backdoor around your web directory, reset all passwords, database info, update your wordpress and login details.

Here are backdoor i found on my client's server:

http://pastebin.com/apAJeJFR

And this one:

http://pastebin.com/vRxEWCqT

Try to use grep to find you have them also.